# How to fix MySQL installation in Ubuntu:20.04 Docker container

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, docker

```
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.
...
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/0: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/1: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/2: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/3: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/4: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/5: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/6: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/7: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/8: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/9: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/10: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/11: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/12: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/13: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/14: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/15: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/16: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/17: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/18: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/19: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/20: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/21: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/22: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/23: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/24: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/25: Permission denied
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've found solution by remove current ubuntu:20.04 docker container, to install ubuntu lastest version for compatibility with docker. And i install mysql-server

```
apt install mysql-server
```